# How do I get back to a self-deleted question?

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-questions

Yesterday I wrote (in a hurry) an admittedly bad question. Now I have a better question to ask, and it's related to what I already wrote.

Is there a way I can go back to that question so I can undelete and edit it, instead of sucking it up and holding the automatic downvote in my bag?

Comment: Have you tried your browser history? As the asker you should still be able to see it if you have a link.

Comment: Good idea Ral Zarek OK this is it. Now what? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969699/is-this-the-shortest-fewest-characters-way-of-making-a-view-source-button

Comment: users less than 10K , can't see own/others deleted question...

Comment: @Lucifer You can't see the question, but you do get a page that says `"This question was voluntarily removed by its author. That's you!"` That should be enough to ID it.

Comment: @Gaffi, yup , i know that part :)

Comment: I've undeleted the question for you.

Comment: @casperOne Thanks Casper. I edited my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flag one of your posts for moderator attention (use Other) and explain you want the question undeleted. Explain which question it was (if there's more than one) and why you want it undeleted. Generally a mod should understand since you *self* deleted it and you want to edit it.

Note it'll be in it's original state immediately after undeletion, so edit fast.

Answer (score 3):

I can see your deleted question, and have put it in a pastebin for you: http://pastebin.com/zG9TYBzR. So you can at least have the content back. As for undeleting, that requires a mod intervention, as it has been said. I could cast an undelete vote on it, but it would also require other users to do the same, and I'm not sure we should do that as a reply to a support request.